# Symfony Security - Checking User Role in constructor of service

Tags: symfony, security

I need to check if a user has admin rights in a service. The function that is being called in this service might be called a whole bunch of times for a single request. One could check for the role of the user once and save the result like this:

```
class myService
{
    private $accessGranted;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
          // user might not be set up yet?
          $accessGranted = $security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
    }

    public function someFunctionWithSecurity()
    {
        if( $accessGranted )
            // do the admin stuff here
        else
            // do slightly different stuff here
    }    
}
```

This seems to work just fine when I test it locally.
I was wondering if there is anything wrong with this setup, or if this will lead to strange/unwanted results.

Comment: This seem works, but is strange. Why don't keep the control of the user in the controller, even with the ACL symfony logic?

Comment: @NicolaPez because the service is a twig extension, as it is used for translation

Comment: umh, ok. So I think is a right way. Also with autowire is would be simple to implement this service around your code.